# ssh connection problem: unusual behaviour

Tags: server, ssh, mac, connection, timeout

I'm perplex about this problem with my ssh connection to my ubuntu server (perplex = not an expert, of course):

1. try to connect my iMac this morning as usual (through LAN): not working. times out without getting through.
2. Try with laptop (mac also): ok (NOTE: using a hotspot from the first the previous computer)
3. Connect iMac to wifi and try: OK!

What's going on? No idea, went though forums and there is no clear explanation why the only blocked session is the one through LAN in my iMac, but no other combo (iMAC/wifi ok, laptop/wifi ok, laptop/hotspot from iMac ok).

ssh -v just freeze in "Connecting to 172.16.1.16 [172.16.1.16] port 22." and then time out.

Please note that this server is for personal use, there is no administrator who could have changed any settings or so. Also, I would like to avoid reboot, there is some weird problem with sudo reboot (again, freeze my ssh) and will have to restart the server (which is not at hand).

It looks like the problem should be in the server that do not allows this specific connection to get through. Is there any way to restart ssh connections/settings?

### EDIT 1

I can see that the problem could be in my iMac. I plugged the laptop to LAN and no went through ok. I also connect trough an alternative LAN setting in my iMac, and agin fails to connect.

---

Hence, any idea how to reset my ssh in my iMac?

(By the way, it is only with this server; I have a second server and its connectio is ok...).

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your setup. Is this Ubuntu server in your home LAN? What do you mean by point (1)? Can you ping 172.16.1.16 from iMac when the iMac is connected to LAN? This seems like a problem with the LAN/router or iMac rather than with the server as another computer (laptop) can connect to the Ubuntu server.

Comment: Have you checked if the iMac on LAN can see the ubuntu server ok? e.g. `ping 172.16.1.16` You should be able to restart the ssh service with `sudo service ssh restart`. Also perhaps edit your question above and include the output of `ifconfig` on your iMac on LAN.

Comment: point (1): using my iMac with lan connection doesn't work. Using mi iMac with wifi work. Using laptop with a hotspot (from lan): works. Yes, I don't quite understand if the problem is in the server or in the iMac.   ping 172.16.1.16 fails 100%; ping in laptop using hotspot-LAN: ok.  sudo service ssh restart: No change